# amazon s3 authorization header invalid

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having problems with amazon s3 authentication.

and the error is pointing to amazon authorization.
it says.

AWS authorization header is invalid.  Expected AwsAccessKeyId:signature

here us my code:

```
   // set default values for optional params first
    bucket = bucket || null;
    path = path || '/';
    query = query || [];
    data = data || null;
    headers = headers || [];
    amazon = amazon || null;

    //get host - bucket1.s3.amazonaws.com
    var host    = this._getHost(bucket);
    //get url - http://bucket1.s3.amazonaws.com/some/path
    var url     = this._getUrl(host, path, query);
    //get path - /bucket1/some/path
    var path    = this._getPath(bucket, path);

    hashed().ksort(amazon);

    // initiatialize variables needed
    var restHeaders = amazonHeaders = [];

    headers.Host = host;
    headers.Date = time().toDate(Date.now(), 'D, d M Y H:i:s T', true);

    for (var header in amazon) {
        restHeaders.push(header+': '+amazon[header]);
        amazonHeaders.push(header.toLowerCase()+':'+amazon[header]);
    }

    for (var header in headers) {
        restHeaders.push(header+': '+headers[header]);
    }

    amazonHeaders = '\n'+amazonHeaders.join('\n');

    if(!amazonHeaders.trim()) {
        amazonHeaders = null;
    }

    if(!(typeof headers['Content-MD5'] !== 'undefined')) {
        headers['Content-MD5'] = null;
    }

    if(!(typeof headers['Content-type'] !== 'undefined')) {
        headers['Content-Type'] = null;
    }

    //get signature
    var signature = [
        action,
        headers['Content-MD5'], 
        headers['Content-Type'],
        headers['Date']+amazonHeaders,
        path];

    signature = signature.join('\n');
    if(headers.Host == 'cloudfront.amazonaws.com') {
        signature = headers.Date;
    }

    restHeaders.push('Host: '+host);
    restHeaders.push('Date: '+headers.Date);
    restHeaders.push('Authorization: '+this._getSignature(signature));
```

please help me, I am forever stuck to this.

Comment: It's not clear to me what `this._getSignature(signature)` is returning or which version of S3 authorization (V2/V4) you're actually trying to use (it looks like (maybe) V2, and I'm not sure why you'd want to do that, since only V4 works in all S3 regions).

Answer (score -3):

For most traditional use cases and applications, you should not write code yourself to compute the signature. You should use AWS supplied SDK for your programming language

See http://aws.amazon.com/tools

These SDK provide higher level functions, easier to use. They manage many of the low level details such as connection management, error handling and... Signatures !

Comment: but I am creating the amazon s3 api for a framework we are creating built in nodejs. it wasn't just making my life terrible now, it was about making life of the developers who will use our framework, light.

Comment: @SébastienStormacq *you should not write code yourself...* that's a very strong assertion and I do not agree.  Many, many of the problems users encounter is because they the SDKs are a crutch that shields them from how the service actually operates and communicates.  If they were actually familiar with the low-level REST interface, they would either avoid these problems, or would not be so mystified by unexpected behavior.  Some of us don't prefer "high level."   I want to talk to the services at the lowest level possible, and have written all of my own AWS libraries for exactly this reason.

Comment: Point taken. But this debate is as old as programming. Should you program in assembly language or with a "high level" C programming language :-)? I, of course, recognize their are use cases where direct access to the REST API is required. And I know developers like to reinvent the wheel rather than reusing libraries developed by someone else :-). But for the vast majority of applications and developers, the SDK will make life simpler. Regarding this question, without knowing anything about context or requirements - the first advice is : use the SDK"

Comment: There is also a SDK for NodeJs that you can embedd in your custom framework

Comment: Completely out of topic. You may have thousands of reasons to write your own code. One very simple reason is when you are using a technology AWS doesn't provide an SDK for.